# If two norms preserves boundedness of sets, then those norms preserves convergence of sequences.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose two norms $|| \cdot||_1$ and $|| \cdot||_2$ for a linear space $X$ preseves boundeddness of sets. i.e $S \subseteq X$ is bdd wrt $|| \cdot||_1$ if and only if $S$ is bdd wrt $|| \cdot||_2$.

Now can we prove that

> if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$ and $x \in X$, 
>   $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ in $|| \cdot||_1$ if and only if $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ in $|| \cdot||_2$

My Attempt:

If we take a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ in $|| \cdot||_1$, then for any $\epsilon \gt0$ there is a $N\in \mathbb Z^+$ s.t $||x_n-x||_1\lt\epsilon$ for $n\gt N$.

thus the set $S=\{x_n-x:n\gt N \}$ is bdd in $||\cdot||_1$ by $\epsilon$. then by hypothesis $S$ is bdd in $||\cdot||_2$. but from here I cannot proceed. Any hint is appreciated.

Edit: My original question askes me to prove the following conditions are equivalent

1.$|| \cdot||_1$ and $|| \cdot||_2$ are equivalent

2.Boundedness of sets is preserved

3.Convergent of sequences is preserved

4.Sequences being Cauchy is preserved.

it is easy to prove 1 $\implies $ 2 and 3 $\implies 4 \implies $ 1.

Comment: Look at the identity function $f:X\to X$. By the assumption applied to the $\|\cdot\|_1$-bounded set $B_1=\{x\in X:\ \|x\|_1\leq 1\}$, we have that there is a $C$ such that for all $x\in B_1$ we have $\|f(x)\|_2\leq C$. Therefore, for $x\in X$ we have that $x/\|x\|_1\in B_1$. Therefore, $\|f(x/\|x\|_1)\|_2\leq C$ gives us $\|x\|_2=\|f(x)\|_2\leq C\|x\|_1$. Therefore, if $x_n-x\to0$ according to $\|\cdot\|_1$ then $x_n-x$ must also tend to $0$ according to $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Comment: Thanks @MoonLightSyzygy

Comment: It is useful to remember the idea of passing from a bound $\|F(x)\|\leq C$ on a bounded set, like a ball, like the unit ball, to a global bound in the form $\|F(x)\|\leq C\|x\|$, by using that $F$ and $\|\cdot\|$ are homogeneous: $\|F(x/\|x\|)\|\leq C\implies \|F(x)\|/\|x\|\leq C\implies \|F(x)\|\leq C\|x\|$.

Comment: I got your point. please add this as an answer. thanks @MoonLightSyzygy